# DataGrid with variable number of columns. Keeping the horizontal scrollbar

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have need of a DataGrid with number of columns determined at run time.  I found this article: 
http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2011/01/23/populating-a-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns-in-a-silverlight-application-using-mvvm.aspx

That shows how to set up a DataGrid with a variable number of columns and it works very well except for one small problem... The horizontal scrollbar does not appear and work when there are many columns of data.  I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that we aren't binding to many properites but only one collection that holds information on all columns.  How can I get a horizontal scrollbar on the grid or even on a container around the grid.

It's a shame, because the solution (from the article above) seems really slick.  Notice the slick use of "List of Lists" to keep the scores associated with each student.  Also notice what a pain it would be to have in the student class a property for each and every score!  Of course, it would be even slicker if you could scroll and see all the data in the grid!

I've tried many things to no avail. I'd really appreciate some help.  I've posted the code below.

-Dave

Edit:  If there is a better (or even different) way to show a variable number of columns in a DataGrid, please point me to some references!
XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer" 
              >
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentStackPanel">


            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                         Binding="{Binding StudentName}"  
                         Header="Name"/>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style 
                      TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter 
                          Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
                          Value="Stretch" />
                                <Setter 
                          Property="VerticalContentAlignment"  
                          Value="Stretch" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" 
                                     Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TitleList}">

                                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel 
                                     Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Border  Width="70" >
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                          TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl  
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectScores}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Border Width="70">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                        TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

and here is the MVVM code (all in one file for simplicity):

```
namespace WpfApplication2
```

{
    /// 
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// 
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

```
public class Student
{
    public String StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public List<decimal> ProjectScores
    {
        get
        {
            List<decimal> list = new List<decimal>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                list.Add(2000 + i);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
public class StudentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Student> _studentList;
    public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentList
    {
        get
        {
            return _studentList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_studentList != value)
            {
                _studentList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StudentList");
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> _titleList;
    public List<string> TitleList
    {
        get
        {
            return _titleList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_titleList != value)
            {
                _titleList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TitleList");
            }
        }
    }

    public StudentViewModel()
    {
        PopulateStudents();
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void PopulateStudents()
    {
        var itemList = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            itemList.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "A very, very, very, very, long student Name: " + i });
        }

        StudentList = itemList;

        var itemNameList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            itemNameList.Add("Header + " + i);
        }
        TitleList = itemNameList;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to remove Width="*" in DataGridTemplateColumn because it modifies the value which the Scrollbar depends.

Doing this will display the scrollbar at the bottom of the DataGrid.
If you will not add other control to the layout, you may not need the StackPanel and the ScrollViewer anymore.